# Unable to import tables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to import few tables from MySQL to MSSQL. Below are the steps I followed in SSIS

```
1). Open the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard.
2). Source connections defined as per  the MySQL ODBC Connector.
3). Destination defined as per MSSQL SQL authentication.
```

now when i try to run the package, i get the following error

```
"you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds right syntax"
```

On digging deep into the issue, i found that it is trying to fetch items using a query

```
Select * from "table"
```

How do i avoid double quotes? I know it is something to do with ANSI_QUOTES, but how do I set ANSI_QUOTES property

Comment: aren't you suppose to use backward quotes for tables in MySql `

Comment: The select script is internally generated by SSIS. I don't know how to modify it

Comment: Open the package in BIDS and edit it there.

Comment: But the package does not get saved because of the error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini` edit the "sql-mode" property.

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ANSI_QUOTES"
                                                                         ^
```